# How to do union of more than two string using VBA Excel without encountering runtime error?

Tags: excel

Hi and hello everyone.

I'm a total novice in this VBA coding and I'm not sure why have I encountered the following error:

> VBA - Runtime error 1004

before this, it was running well but as I added more to my range, this error popped out and the debugger keep pointing to `Set myRng = Application.Union(.Range(myCopy), .Range(myCopy2))`.

I don't know how to fix this part of code and here I provide the full code

```html
Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()

    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet

    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim oCol As Long

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myCopy As String
    Dim myCopy2 As String
    Dim myCell As Range
    
    'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
    myCopy = "D10, D12, D14, D16, D18, D20, D22, D24, D26, D28, D30, D32, D34, D36, D38, D40, D42, D46, D48, D50, D52, D54, D56, D58, D60, D62, D64, D66, D68, D70,D72, D74, D78, D80, D82, D86, D88, D90, D92, D94, D96, D98, D100, D102, D104, D106, D108, D110, D113"
    myCopy2 = "D115, D119, D121, D123, D125, D127, D129, D131, D133, D137, D139, D141, D143, D145, D147, D149, D151, D153, D155, D159, D163, D168, D170, D174, D178, D182, D184, D186, D191, D193, D195, D199, D201, D205, D203, D207, D209, D211, D215, D217, D219, D221, D223"
    
    
    Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("IncidentDatabase")

    With historyWks
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

    With inputWks
        Set myRng = Application.Union(.Range(myCopy), .Range(myCopy2))
    End With
    

    Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("IncidentDatabase")

    With historyWks
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

    With inputWks
        Set myRng = Union(.Range(myCopy), .Range(myCopy2))

        If Application.CountA(myRng) <> myRng.Cells.Count Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    With historyWks
        With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        End With
        .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
        oCol = 3
        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
            historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
            oCol = oCol + 1
        Next myCell
    End With
    
    'clear input cells that contain constants
    With inputWks
      On Error Resume Next
         With .Range(myCopy).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
              .ClearContents
              Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
         End With
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

I know that there's already countless of questions regarding VBA run time error 1004 but as I keep reading through them, I didn't find the answer.

Every help and guidance is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the len of myCopy2 is over 255 in length. The max is 255 characters for the string.

You can subdivide that range to be under the limit

```
myCopy = "D10, D12, D14, D16, D18, D20, D22, D24, D26, D28, D30, D32, D34, D36, D38, D40, D42, D46, D48, D50, D52, D54, D56, D58, D60, D62, D64, D66, D68, D70,D72, D74, D78, D80, D82, D86, D88, D90, D92, D94, D96, D98, D100, D102, D104, D106, D108, D110, D113"
myCopy2 = "D115, D119, D121, D123, D125, D127, D129, D131, D133, D137, D139, D141, D143, D145, D147, D149, D151, D153, D155, D159, D163, D168, D170, D174, D178, D182, D184, D186, D191, D193, D195, D199, D201, D205, D203, D207, D209, D211, D215"
Dim myCopy2b As String
myCopy2b = "D217, D219, D221, D223"


Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
Set historyWks = Worksheets("IncidentDatabase")

With historyWks
    nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End With

With inputWks
    Set myRng = Application.Union(.Range(myCopy), .Range(myCopy2), .Range(myCopy2b))
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.

Comment: Uhm, I've done as suggested, but still got the same problem.

Comment: Did the above not work? It seemed to work when I tested.

Comment: once again pointed to Set myRng = Application.Union(.Range(myCopy), .Range(myCopy2), .Range(myCopy2b)) although I follow exactly as you told me

Comment: I have to wonder then if the contents of the cell are causing the problem when combined. It you run the above using an empty sheet do you get the same error? I get the msgbox "Please fill in all the cells"

Comment: Looks like I did wrong on the content side. Now it's working fine. Thank you and sorry for the trouble.